# Bluetooth not starting on Arch

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arch-linux

I am suffering from a bluetooth problem with an external CSR dongle. I can see the device with `lsusb`

Trying to start the daemon manually via:

```
sudo /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -n
```

gives me:

```
bluetoothd[5103]: Bluetooth daemon 5.40
bluetoothd[5103]: Starting SDP server
bluetoothd[5103]: Bluetooth management interface 1.12 initialized
bluetoothd[5103]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
bluetoothd[5103]: Sap driver initialization failed.
bluetoothd[5103]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
bluetoothd[5103]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like rfkill is blocking it. To resolve this you can try:

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```